# MYSQL Workbench Status

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Can anybody explain what does the 'Total connection attempts' and
'Threads connected' mean ?

Is the 'Total connection attempts' acts as a counter log that counts all of the connections to the current time ?

If you see it shows 8339, is this OK ? does it mean I have 8339 connections open or does the 'Threads connected' which value is 88 shows the open connections to MYSQL ?

[Workbench Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6RGl.png)

Answer (score 0):

These are accumulated values IIRC, which means the represent the total count of threads and connection attempts since last reset, rather than current counts.